# How to use two different Google fonts in Next.js with Material UI app?

Tags: css, next.js, material-ui, fonts

Currently migrating my MUI5 app with Next 12 to Next 13 and trying to make use of `next/font`.
In my Next 12 version, I was using two Google fonts - `'Rubik'` and `'Ephesis'` and since they were imported into the `<head>`, they were accessible globally using CSS.

For example, I was able to write `<Typography fontFamily='Ephesis' children='Hi' />` and it would work.

However, now, with `next/font`, I don't know how to implement both font families globally so that something like the `<Typography>` above works!

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Have your tried the new [font module](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/font) that was introduced some time ago?

Comment: Hi, yes, I am trying to use next/font/google

Answer (score 0):

See [this section](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/font#using-a-font-definitions-file) in the official documentation about using multiple fonts and using them in multiple places using a font definitions file.

```
import { Roboto, Inter } from 'next/font/google';

export const inter = Inter();
export const roboto = Roboto({ weight: '400', subsets: ['latin'] });
```

And then somewhere in your application you could import the fonts like this:

```
import { roboto, inter } from './my-font-file';

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p className={roboto.className}>I am in Roboto font</p>
      <p className={inter.className}>I am in Inter font</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I considered this, but it just felt clunky...having to import the secondary font e.g. `inter` every time. Is this really the best approach?

Comment: I do not know how exactly the scoping of this class names is, maybe it would also suffice if you'd just provide it inside your `layout.tsx`'s body tag and then provide the `fontFamily` prop to your typography component.