# Next JS 13 Multiple Fonts Per Layout

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a website which has a root layout for the customer facing website and a separate layout for the dashboard.

I'm trying to have one font for the client facing website (i.e the brand font) and a more standard font for the dashboard (i.e. easier readability).

Here is my code in each layout.

### ROOT

```
import "./globals.css";
import { jost } from "./utility/font";

export const metadata = {
  title: "TITLE",
  description: "DESCRIPTION",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={jost.className}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

### DASHBOARD

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={inter.className}>
      <body>
        <AuthContextProvider>
          <div className="flex w-screen">
            <div className="w-[280px]">
              <Sidebar />
            </div>

            <div className="flex-grow sticky top-0">
              <Navbar />
              <main>{children}</main>
            </div>
          </div>
        </AuthContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

### FONT.JS

```
import { Jost } from "next/font/google";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

export const jost = Jost({ subsets: ["latin"] });
export const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
```

However I am getting the below error:

> Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "__className_fe0236"
> Client: "__className_0ec1f4"

I'm aware this error indicates theres a mismatch from the server to the client, but the font doesn't change in the dashboard page.

I know there is a way to dismiss this error however, i believe it will not fix the font issue. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

### FOLDER STRUCTURE

```
 -src

 --app

 ---dashboard/

 ----layout.jsx

 ----page.jsx

 ---layout.jsx

 ---page.jsx
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76457420/8003058) answer your question?

Comment: @FabioNettis I saw this and it's fine for placing fonts for individual elements, however, I would prefer to have my fonts in my layouts. The reason being is because each layout is a root and I should just be able to apply the font to each layout. Rather than adding it to each element. Unless I'm missing something, and it's not possible?

Comment: You can add it to your layout just the same as you would apply it to any other element, if none of its children defines its own font rules the child elements will inherit the style from their parent.

Comment: @FabioNettis I'm doing that to the HTML element in each layout, however, the font doesn't change on the Dashboard Layout, it keeps the font from the Root Layout.

Comment: Are your layouts nested or are you using [route groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups)? Because if you are not, that is probably the way to go.

Comment: @FabioNettis I've created a different Layout for each 1. Main Website 2. Dashboard. I will add my folder structure to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254191/discussion-between-fabio-nettis-and-david-henry).